# Jmeter WebDriver Sampler resulting in 'unknown protocol: data'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am currently trying to put load on HTTPS website by using Webdriver Sampler in Jmeter. Jmeter successfully runs the whole Selenium code in Webdriver Sampler; but in the end, marks the sampler as *Failed* in 'View Results Tree' listener. Response data > Response Body shows

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data

It's strange, as it already has executed the whole code successfully with even closing the browser. What's the point of giving this error in the end?

What is the way out to avoid this failure?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you open the browser and don't call [WebDriver.get() function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-)

Please inspect all your [WebDriver Samplers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and ensure that there is the following call in each of them:

```
WDS.browser.get('https://example.com')
```

replace `example.com` with the URL of the application you're testing.

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more information on Selenium scripting in JMeter, troubleshooting, tips and tricks.

Comment: I called driver.get() function in every WebDriver Sampler. Also, I used Java (instead of JavaScript) language in the sampler. Anyway after much time invested in this, I successfully ran the case using JUnit sampler.